# Having it both ways with rank-n-types

Tags: haskell, existential-type, rank-n-types

I'm playing with a ConduitT style monad that uses existential quantification, and I'm playing whack-a-mole trying to get the types to unify. There's two versions of this scenario:

Here, `Await i` has an existentially quantified `a`, which allows the `await` method to pass it whatever type of `i -> Await i -> a` that it wants.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Piped r a = Piped { unPiped :: forall b. r -> (r -> a -> b) -> b }

instance Functor (Piped r) where                              
  fmap f (Piped c) = Piped $ \r rest -> c r (\r -> rest r . f)

runPiped :: Piped r a -> r -> a      
runPiped (Piped p) r = p r $ \_ -> id

newtype Await i = Await { unAwait :: forall a. Yield i a -> a }           
newtype Yield i a = Yield { unYield :: i -> Await i -> a }                

runAwait :: Await i -> (i -> Await i -> a) -> a                           
runAwait (Await await) = await . Yield                                    

runYield :: Yield i a -> i -> (Yield i a -> a) -> a                       
runYield (Yield yield) i = yield i . Await
                     -- broke        ^^^^^
                     -- because Await swallows the type of `a`                                

await :: forall i a y. Piped (Await i, y) i                               
await = Piped $                                                           
  \(a, y) f -> runAwait a $ \i a' -> f (a', y) i
```

Fails with:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Yield i a -> a’
                 with ‘forall a1. Yield i a1 -> a1’
  Expected type: (Yield i a -> a) -> Await i
    Actual type: (forall a. Yield i a -> a) -> Await i
• In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘Await’
```

The `runYield` method is broken because it can't unify the existentially qualified type parameter in `Await i` with `a`.

Second scenario:

In order to fix `runYield`, `Await` now specifies `a`, which unifies `Await i a` with `Yield i a`. However, now that `a` is specified, `yield` can't pass it an `Yield i b` with any value of `b` that it pleases:

```
newtype Piped r a = Piped { unPiped :: forall b. r -> (r -> a -> b) -> b }
newtype Await i a = Await { unAwait :: Yield i a -> a }                   
newtype Yield i a = Yield { unYield :: i -> Await i a -> a }              

runAwait :: Await i a -> (i -> Await i a -> a) -> a                       
runAwait (Await await) = await . Yield                                    

runYield :: Yield i a -> i -> (Yield i a -> a) -> a                       
runYield (Yield yield) i = yield i . Await                                

await :: Piped (Await i a, y) i                                           
await = Piped $                                                           
  \(a, y) f -> runAwait a $ \i a' -> f (a', y) i                          
-- ^^^^^^
```

Fails with:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘a’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a type expected by the context:
      forall b. (Await i a, y) -> ((Await i a, y) -> i -> b) -> b
  Expected type: (Await i a, y)
    Actual type: (Await i b, y)
```

So I appear to need it both ways, existentially quantified sometimes and concrete other times. I've tried creating wrappers to hide the extra type parameter, switching `newtype` for `data`, and it also occurred to me that if i could define a function `Await i a -> Await i b` that might also solve the issue but I'm a bit out of my depth here. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, switching between `newtype` and `data` has no hope of helping you solve any type errors, unless the type declaration itself produces an error.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `runYield :: Yield i a -> i -> (forall a2 . Yield i a2 -> a2) -> a` ? With your signature it looks incorrect to me -- you need the rank-2 type.

Comment: This seems to produce the same error as in the first scenario.

Comment: Am I being dense? I don't see any existential variables. `data Await i = Await i (Await i)` and `newtype Yield i a = Yield (Await i -> a)` if you remove all the CPS, no? It's rank-1 universal quantification all the way through?

Comment: I retract my answer; @chi's comment is the way to go, I think. You might need to rewrite `runYield` in pointful form to make it work.

Comment: Did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem once I tried to define the `yield` function; i had to remove the extra type variable from `yield` and it wouldn't typecheck.

The solution turned out to be to redefine the types as such:

```
newtype Await i = Await { unAwait :: forall b. Yield' i b -> b }     
newtype Yield i = Yield { unYield :: forall b. i -> Await' i b -> b }

type Await' i a = Yield i -> a                                       
type Yield' i a = i -> Await i -> a
```

This way, there's no additional constructor to swallow type variables in `await`:

```
await :: Piped (Await i, y) i                  
await = Piped $                                
  \(Await a, y) f -> a $ \i a' -> f (a', y) i
```